# Dreamweaver mismatching/broken code at http links

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I have a strange issue with dreamweaver, editing HTML/PHP code.
When I save a .php or .html file and then re-open it in dreamweaver, it is showing broken href links, sometimes with missing closing " therefore breaking the code from that point on.

Here is an example:

This is the code when I save the file:

```
<tr> 
            <td><b><span style='color:#FF6464;'>Route:</span><br><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1vKhfQCoJJf0jNWaf2a9NOl5L3bVbvgU&usp" target="_blank" style='color:yellow;'>GOOGLE MAPS</a></b></td>
            </tr>
```

BUT, when I reopen the same file, dreamweaver will show me this:

```
<tr> 
            <td><b><span style='color:#FF6464;'>Route:</span><br><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1vKhfQCoJJf0jNWaf2a9NOl5L3bVbvgU&usp"_blank" style='color:yellow;'>GOOGLE MAPS</a> </b></td>
</tr>
```

so this bit is missing here: target="

Another one on the same page:
Saved this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=14atrlaqcxoM51Fr1nChkNUWA-lkF2NY&usp4sharing" target="_blank" style='color:yellow;'>GOOGLE MAPS</a>
```

When close and re-open the file, shows this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=14atrlaqcxoM51Fr1nChkNUWA-lkF2NY&usp4sha"_blank" style='color:yellow;'>GOOGLE MAPS</a>
```

If I open the file in another app like Notepad++, it's fine there.
Have had this issue with other type of links too, e.g. facebook pixel etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't use that editor, but perhaps it gets confused by `&usp` because it isn't a valid HTML entity. You may want to try encoding the URL, as in `&amp;usp`.

Comment: That seems to be it! Thank you!!